# Bonferroni inequality proof

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, proof-verification

Is this proof for $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i)\le\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_i)$ correct?

*Pf*. By induction. For $n=2$, $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\le P(A)+P(B)$$
Assume that the statement is true for $n-1$, that is: $$P(\bigcup_{1}^{n-1}A_i)\le\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P(A_i)$$ Let $B=\bigcup_{1}^{n-1}A_i$,

$$P(B\cup A_n)\le P(B)+P(A_n)\le \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}P(A_i) + P(A_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct. Maybe it would be better to point out that you use the induction assumption in the second inequality, while the first uses the result for $n=2$.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas for extending to a countably infinite union $$P(\bigcup_1^\infty A_i)$$?

Comment: For each $n$, $\mathbb P(\bigcup_{j=1}^nA_j)\leqslant \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mathbb P(A_j)$. Then use and show the fact that $\mathbb P(\bigcup_{j=1}^nA_j)\uparrow \mathbb P(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j)$.

Comment: What is this arrow notation?

Comment: Convergence and the sequence is non-decreasing